# Plugin default settings hook

Tags: filters, actions, callbacks

I am writing a plugin where I want it's default settings to change in accordance to the theme that is selected. I have it working, but would rather provide an action hook for this instead of writing the specifically named function as I have here. Is there a better method for this using `do_action` and `add_action` possibly?

PLUGIN ADMIN PHP:

```
function bf_set_defaults(){
  $default_settings = array(
    // Header
      'embers_header_nav_pos' => 'bottom',
      'embers_header_leftcol' => '4',
      'embers_header_middlecol' => '4',
      'embers_header_rightcol' => '4',

    // Full Width Content
      'embers_full_width_contentcol' => '12',

    // Content Sidebar
      'embers_content_sidebar_contentcol' => '8',
      'embers_content_sidebar_primarycol' => '4',

    //Sidebar Content
      'embers_sidebar_content_contentcol' => '8',
      'embers_sidebar_content_primarycol' => '4',

    // Content Sidebar Sidebar
      'embers_content_sidebar_sidebar_contentcol' => '6',
      'embers_content_sidebar_sidebar_primarycol' => '4',
      'embers_content_sidebar_sidebar_secondarycol' => '2',

    // Sidebar Sidebar Content
      'embers_sidebar_sidebar_content_contentcol' => '8',
      'embers_sidebar_sidebar_content_primarycol' => '4',
      'embers_sidebar_sidebar_content_secondarycol' => '2',
      'embers_sidebar_sidebar_content_contentsidebar' => '10',

    // Sidebar Content Sidebar
      'embers_sidebar_content_sidebar_contentcol' => '8',
      'embers_sidebar_content_sidebar_primarycol' => '4',
      'embers_sidebar_content_sidebar_secondarycol' => '2',
      'embers_sidebar_content_sidebar_contentsidebar' => '10',
    );

  if (function_exists('bf_new_defaults')) {
   return bf_new_defaults( $default_settings );
  }else{
   return $default_settings;
  }

}

// Create the Admin Page
$this->create( $page_id, $menu_ops, $page_ops, $settings_field, bf_set_defaults() );
```

THEME functions.php:

```
function bf_new_defaults( $default_settings ) {
 $default_settings['embers_header_nav_pos'] = 'top';
 $default_settings['embers_header_leftcol'] = '8';
 return $default_settings;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a filter. You can remove this:

```
if (function_exists('bf_new_defaults')) {
    return bf_new_defaults( $default_settings );
} else {
    return $default_settings;
}
```

and replace it with something like this:

```
 return apply_filters('bf_filter', $default_settings)
```

The following is a truncated, proof of concept version of the code so you can see how `$default_settings` gets altered.

```
add_filter(
    'bf_filter',
    function($default_settings) {
        var_dump($default_settings);
        $default_settings[] = 4;
        return $default_settings;
    }
);
$default_settings = array(1, 2, 3);
var_dump(apply_filters('bf_filter', $default_settings));
```

Your filter has to be added before `bf_set_defaults` runs so you may have trouble with the fact that plugins load before themes, but it depends on how (when) the function is used.

Comment: I am confused at where things would go from your code, however, the PLUGIN ADMIN PHP file gets `include`ed at `after_theme_setup`. What pieces then would go in which files?

Comment: @NathanPowell : I edited to make it more clear, I hope.

Comment: I don't want to break site rules, would it be proper for me to post the final code as an answer you think? for anyone else?